# How can I define multiple agents in declarative jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, agent, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

In my Jenkinsfile I want a particular stage to run on both the agents in parallel.for example:

```
stage('abc'){
  agent {
    label "dev6" && "dev7"
  }
  steps {
    xyz()
  }
}
```

I have two slaves with label dev6 and dev7. I want xyz() to start on both the agents dev6 and dev7 at same time parallely. What is the correct way to do it? Do i need parallel block ? from the above code it just starts the functions on one of dev6 or dev7. I tried with

```
label "dev6 || dev7"

label "dev6 && dev7"
```

but it doenst work. Can someone help??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parallel on level of stages, the reason for that is actually you want this to run twice on separate agents. Unless I misunderstood you.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            parallel {
                stage('Test On dev6') {
                    agent {
                        label "dev6"
                    }
                    steps {
                        xyz()
                    }
                }
                stage('Test On dev7') {
                    agent {
                        label "dev7"
                    }
                    steps {
                        xyz()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for me :)
Can I add some regex in label of the agent. So that I have only one stage block and if the expression matches that regex it will start that job on all the slaves matching that regex label

<code>pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            parallel {
                stage( TEST) {
                    agent {
                        label "SOME REGEX"
                    }
                    steps {
                        xyz()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }</code>

Comment: I'm not sure you can do that to be honest.